# Speed and direction of object after ball-to-ball collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I'm trying to realistically lower the speed of a ball and also possibly change the direction of it if needed. I got no idea how to count the collision angle impact on the speed and at which angle the ball should change direction. I just want to know the idea behind this collision detection but if somebody has ready to implement code for Unity C#, even better. I made  this awesome image to demonstrate my question.

[image: Different collisions affect speed and direction differently]

Comment: Just use the internal physics engine.

Comment: you mean two moving balls? or ball + generic object

Comment: I think you are not using physics and bounciness

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't know that Unity contains a built-in physic engine.
To use it, simply add a Rigidbody component and a Collider Component (BoxCollider, SphereCollider, ...) to your objects.

In code, you can give your objects a speed, acceleration on so on by using the rigidbody. Example:

```
gameobject.rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f);
```

The doc contains all the functions you can call on rigidbodies:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html

If two objects that have rigidbodies and colliders touch each other, the collidion is automatically computed. Note that the new direction of the objects are computed using the collider object's shape, so you need to use a collider that looks as much as possible like your object.

Good luck